# The header of the ListView is not shown in a MAUI ListView

Tags: maui

I have a listview with some columns and I would like to show the headers. In the documentation I see that it is possible in this way:

```
<ListView.Header>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">
        <Label Margin="10,0,0,0"
       Text="Monkeys"
       FontSize="12"
       FontAttributes="Bold" />
    </StackLayout>
</ListView.Header>
<ListView.Footer>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">
        <Label Margin="10,0,0,0"
       Text="Friends of Monkey"
       FontSize="12"
       FontAttributes="Bold" />
    </StackLayout>
</ListView.Footer>
```

But in my case I don't see anything. Neither a red background color neither the text.

```
<ListView x:Name="lvRegistrosHorarios" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,20,0,0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
                  IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                  RefreshCommand="{Binding MyrefreshCommand}"
                  IsRefreshing="{Binding isRefreshing}"
                  BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                  SeparatorColor="DarkBlue">


            <ListView.Header>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">
                    <Label Margin="10,0,0,0"
                   Text="Monkeys"
                   FontSize="12"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.Footer>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">
                    <Label Margin="10,0,0,0"
                   Text="Friends of Monkey"
                   FontSize="12"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Footer>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Text="{Binding COlumn1}" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

                            <Label Text="{Binding COlumn2}" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            
                            <Label Text="{Binding COlumn3}" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            
                            <Label Text="{Binding COlumn4}" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

How could show the header?

Thanks.

Comment: I use the same code but works well on iOS and Android. What platform do you use?

Comment: Right, it works, but it in my case it hasn't space because of another control.

Comment: Okay if you still have any question, you could share it here. We can work together to figure it out.

Comment: related (according to a non-answer posted as an answer): https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12312